# Is it possible to use Metal data types in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I want to use some of the vector data types defined in Metal (such as `uint2`, [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/data-types/data-types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH2-SW1)) in Objective-C for my iOS app.  However, I haven't been able to find any information about whether or not this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those types are in `<simd/SIMD.h>` for C and C++ (and by extension, for Objective-C and Objective-C++).

They're actually the same types, with the same data layout, and the same associated functions, as those that you use from a Metal shader. So using them in CPU-side code where you expect to interface with Metal is a great idea. For example, you can define your own struct for vertex shader input in a C++ header file, then import that header and use the same struct definition in both your CPU code and the shader.

Note that the names differ a bit: e.g. `uint2` is `vector_uint2` in C, but `simd::uint2` in C++.

Comment: Just asking ,  can i rename my Obj-C file to *.mm, and mix C++ into objective-c and use vector data types ? is it a solution ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it's there for.

Comment: I use the simd.h vector types in my C/C++/ObjC vector code all the time. I prefer them to the vendor specific types found in xmmintrin.h / arm_neon.h, because they properly encode the full type of the element (unlike say __m128i) and can use standard operators +-*/&^|, etc. in clang.  It allows you to write portable vector code for any Apple platform.